# Stabilizing test methods in one test class

Tags: java, selenium, selenium-webdriver, automated-tests, testng

I have a test class using testNG, with 4 test methods, testing one website for 4 different browsers, like the following code:

```
public class MyTest {
    @Test
    public void acceptanceFFTest()
    {
    }
    @Test
    public void acceptanceChromeTest()
    {
    }
    @Test
    public void acceptanceIETest()
    {
    }
    @Test
    public void acceptanceSafariTest()
    {
    }
    @AfterMethod
    public void tearDown()
    {
        webDriver.quit();
    }
}
```

After one test method finished, the webdriver for that browser is killed in the @AfterMethod, the next browser starts with new webdriver respectively, and so on.

My problem is: if I run these test methods one by one, then they are always passed. But if I run from the test class level as a test suite with 4 test methods, then sometimes one or two of them are failed with NoElementException, But the exception is not always at one page or one element, sometimes here, sometimes there. If I run the failed tests alone again, then they are passed.

I think for the test class level, maybe the http signal sometimes is fast and sometimes is slow, the test class level is not stable as single test method, I am not sure.

Is there anyway to stabilize them? Thank you.

Comment: What is the exception thrown when they fail? Also, it's hard to tell you why if you don't share the actual tests.

Comment: @RemcoW: it's NoElement exception. But it's not at always one page or one element, sometimes here, sometimes there. And as I said, when I run failed tests alone again, they are passed. So, I can't really think of something to stabilize them.

Comment: You have to provide more code. Your draft is good and should work, but I think the problem is your implementation.

Comment: You should write your tests in such a way that you don't need different tests for each browser. Write once and run on all.

Comment: @JeffC: It's the question for me. I tried to find a way to do that, write once and run on all. But for different browsers, we need different webdrivers. If you have a good practice example, I would appreciate so much. Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would rewrite the tests so that you have a single test that runs on all browsers. You may run into some slight differences in the browser that you may have to handle but I think this overall approach is much better and more manageable.  Here's a simple example of how to do this. For this example I just hardcoded a string `browserType`. I'm assuming you would pass this in or read it from a file or whatever. The basic idea is that you define your `driver` variable as a generic `WebDriver`. Once you determine what browser you want for that run, you instantiate the specific driver and execute the test(s).

```
String browserType = "firefox"; // hardcoded for the example
WebDriver driver;

switch (browserType)
{
    case "firefox":
        driver = new FirefoxDriver();
        break;
    case "ie":
        driver = new InternetExplorerDriver();
        break;
    case "chrome":
        driver = new ChromeDriver();
        break;
    default:
        throw new Exception("browserType: " + browserType + " not defined.");
}

// do test case
driver.get("http://www.google.com");
// ... and so on
```

Comment: Thank you. Based on your idea, I pass the `browser` from `testng.xml`, and I write the switch in `BeforeMethod`, so now I have a single test that runs on all browsers. Thanks again.